# Detecting back or set wallpaper button pressed on a livewallpaper preview mode screen?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Do you know a way to detect that the back or set wallpaper button is pressed on a livewallpaper preview mode screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnDestroy() is called when you backpress in that screen. If you choose to set the wallpaper, OnDestroy() is also called. Unfortunately Theres no Overriding onBackPressed(), onPause() or onStop() in a WallpaperService preview.

Heres the order of Lifecycle methods that are called when you start the preview for the first time :

```
OnCreate() ->

OnSharedPreferencesChanged() (if you have any) ->

OnCreate(SurfaceHolder) (Engine subclass) ->

OnSurfaceCreated() (Engine subclass) ->

OnSurfaceChanged() (Engine subclass) ->

OnVisibilityChanged(true) (Engine subclass) ->

OnVisibilityChanged(false) (Engine subclass) ->

OnVisibilityChanged(true) (Engine subclass) ->

OnOffsetsChanged (Engine subclass)
```

With the method isPreview() of your Engine Subclass you can at least check if your wallpaper is running in Preview Mode or not.